# Multiple portal on a single salesforce instance

Tags: lightning-community

I am planning to create multiple communities for a single user. The plan is user will register once and use multiple communities. Is there any issues with this approach ? or there are better ways to do it ?

Comment: The user's profile will need access to all settings for all your portals which may or may not be desirable

Comment: Why would you that in the first place? If the same User is logging in, then you should infact put all information at one place.

Comment: @RedDevil, Thanks for the point ! Makes sense.

Comment: @JayantDas, There are two different programs or vendors suppose. I don't want them to have same look and feel (not talking about branding at all) . Some different UI , but there could be same user for both of the vendors..something like this requirement I am looking for options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Working with Lightning Communities, there are settings that can be found in the community's Workspace -> Administration -> Members

You can either set the member access to the community based on Profiles, permission sets, or both. You could have users go through registration where they are given permission sets to access both communities.

Depending on your existing security model requirements, this might be a terrible idea (as RedDevil said previously). Take your time to plan around those specifics.

Comment: Mitchel : Yes, It's possible to do , and I already did a POC on that. And you are right , the security is a concern. Appreciate the pointers :)